# I'm using firebase database, I just wanna know if can I or how can I retrieve data inside of two sub childs?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

[This is the structure of my database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu0gY.png)

[image]

I want to get all the outcome value, but I need to loop the faculty child first and the exam child before I able to use the getValue() in outcome. How can I loop the faculty child and exam child in the same time?

This is my code, but I don't know how to get to the Exam child and loop it again to get the outcome value.

```
 dbOutcome.child("sample_list").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, can you add some code showing what have you done so far? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get all the outcome value

Assuming that the `sample_list` node is a direct child of your Firebase root, to solve this, you need use `getChildren()` method twice:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("sample_list");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String outcome = ds.child("outcome").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", outcome);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
pass
fail
pass
fail
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the models classes to retrieve this.
Make **model classes** and get data in them

```
public class Exam {
   pirvate String outcomes;
// create constructor and getter setter
}
```

create Faculty class

```
public class Faculty {
   List<Exam> exams

// create constructor and getter setter
}
```

**get Data from snapshot in onDataChange** like this

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Faculty> faculties = (ArrayList<Faculty>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)